# Select estado cidade rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4

Tenho um select dinâmico de Estados e cidades
e minha ideia é lista a capital do estado selecionado primeiro.

tenho o seguinte codigo para listar as cidades mas que nao esta listando a capital primeiro:

```
@cidades = Cidade.where("estado_id = ?", Estado.first.id).order(id: Estado.select(:capital))
```

lembrando que a capital é um atributo da tabela Estado do tipo integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra ordenar por valores específicos vc tem que usar um case.

```
@cidades = Cidade.where("estado_id = ?", Estado.first.id).order("CASE id
WHEN #{Estado.select(:capital).id} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")
```